# How to check opened popup window records save in database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My popup window code is this -

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function call(URL,ids,url_id,user_id,plan_id) {
    popup = window.open(URL, URL,'minimizable=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, titlebar=no');
    setTimeout(function(){
        popup.close()
        $('#'+ids).attr("href", "#");

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "index.php?act=url_records",
                data: {
                    user_id: user_id, url_id: url_id, plan_id: plan_id
                }, 
                success: function (data) {       
                    if(data == "Ok"){

                    }
                },
            });
    }, 5000);
}
</script>
<div id="page-wrapper" class="well" style="border:solid 1px #E8E7FE;">
    <div class="container-fluid"><br />
        <div class="well row bg-title">
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <h4 class="page-title" style="color:#AE1534;">Inbox</h4> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="well white-box" style="overflow-x:auto;"><br />
                    {$iv=1}
                    {foreach $records as $value}
                        {$iv}:
                             <a href="javascript:call('{$value.url_name}','id_{$iv}','{$value.url_id}','{$smarty.session.UserId}','{$smarty.session.PlanId}')" style="color:#0000C1; text-decoration:underline;" id="id_{$iv}">{$value.url_name}</a>
                             <br /><br />
                        {$iv++}     
                  {/foreach}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

when the user click on the link then popup window is open and after 5 second popup window is automatically closed and records save in database.
But the problem is this - when the user has to close the opened popup window but records also save in database.
I want to
if user has to close the opened popup window then record shouldn't saved in database...

Comment: On closing of pop window event clear the time out function like this  var myVar = setTimeout(function(){ ......ajax......});    clearTimeout(myVar);

Comment: how `popup.close()` is called by the user ? or how the user closes the popup